# Adding a telephone field to my form emailer. And outputting it

Tags: php, mail-form

I'm not the greatest with PHP but I managed to use this pre existing code to get my new telephone field validated like the rest. Now I don't know exactly where to put it in order for it to be added to my email. I tried a couple spots but the form stopped working all together.

```
<?php


header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$admin_email = 'info@indabahairstudio.ca'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

    $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
    $this->email = trim($details['email']);
    $this->telephone = stripslashes($details['telephone']);

    $this->subject = 'Appointment Request'; // Subject 
    $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

    $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
    $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

    $this->response_status = 1;
    $this->response_html = '';
}


private function validateEmail(){
    $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

    if($this->email == '') { 
        return false;
    } else {
        $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
    }

    return empty($string) ? true : false;
}


private function validateFields(){
    // Check name
    if(!$this->name)
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your name</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check email
    if(!$this->email)
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter an e-mail address</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check phone number
    if(!$this->telephone)
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter a telephone number</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check valid email
    if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter a valid e-mail address</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }

    // Check message length
    if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
    {
        $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your message. It should have at least '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p>';
        $this->response_status = 0;
    }
}


private function sendEmail(){
    $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
         "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

    if($mail)
    {
        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
    }
}


function sendRequest(){
    $this->validateFields();
    if($this->response_status)
    {
        $this->sendEmail();
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
    $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
 }


$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, $message_min_length);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

 ?>
```

Comment: `private function sendEmail(){
    $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->telephone,
         "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
        ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

    if($mail)
    {
        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
    }`

Comment: That was my first guess /\

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I joined it with a "." to the "$this->message"

Its not pretty when out putted, but it works! :D